# how to delete objects in core data

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, uimanageddocument

I am trying to understand how core data works. 
So I have in my core data 2 entities : Voiture and Garage (yes, i'm french :) )

I can create objects but i can't delete them ! I tried everything…
It would be nice to help me a bit !

here is my code :

```
@interface dataBaseViewController ()

@property(strong,nonatomic) UIManagedDocument *document;
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *context;

@end

@implementation dataBaseViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a

[self initDocument];

self.context=self.document.managedObjectContext;

}


-(void) initDocument{



//find url
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *documentsDirectory=[[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];
NSString *documentName=@"MyDocument";
NSURL *url= [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:documentName];


 //create / open the document
    self.document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url] ;

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]]) {

        [self.document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
                if (success) NSLog(@"doc ouvert");
                  if (!success) NSLog(@"couldn’t open document at %@", url);
              }];

        } else {

            [self.document saveToURL:url forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
                if (success)        NSLog(@"document created");
              if (!success) NSLog(@"couldn’t create document at %@", url);
        }];
        }
}



- (IBAction)ajouterVoiture:(id)sender {
Voiture *nouvelleVoiture =[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Voiture" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
nouvelleVoiture.marque=@"ferreri";

}
- (IBAction)nbVoitures:(id)sender {
NSError *error;
NSFetchRequest *request=[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Voiture"];

NSLog(@"nombre de voitures : %lu",[self.context countForFetchRequest:request error:&error]);
}


- (IBAction)delete:(id)sender {
   [self.context deletedObjects];
   NSError *error;
   [self.context save:&error];
}


@end
```

Comment: See NSManagedObjectContext [`deleteObject:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001182-BAJGGEHJ)

Comment: Why you did: **self.context=self.document.managedObjectContext;** ? try with statement: **[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:anObject];**

Answer (score 3):

Once you have fetched a managed object, you can delete it from its managed object context by using the deleteObject: method provided by the context.

```
NSManagedObject *someObject;

[context deleteObject:someObject];
```

The object will not be removed from the underlying persistent store on disk until the context is saved, using the save: method.

Comment: the thing is that i would like to create an object in one function and the delete it in another function… It still doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Your context has to be visible in (1) where you create the object, (2) where you delete it and (3) where you do the save.  I do all my DB interactions in a class named SpS_DB.  In the classes' .h file, I allocate a strong property for the context and then later in my .m file I can access it as [self context].  My code is simple,  The delete and save look like this: 
[[self context] deleteObject:theObject];
[self context] save: &err];
THere's a bit more to it than that but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I *highly* recommend the [Magical Record](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) pod. It *greatly* simplifies boilerplate Core Data operations.

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlockAndWait:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    MyEntity *entity = [MyEntity MR_createInContext:localContext];
    MyOtherEntity *otherEntity = [MyOtherEntity MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"id" withValue:12345];

    entity.attribute1 = @"Foo";
    entity.attribute2 = @"Bar";

    [otherEntity deleteInContext:localContext];
}];
```

Comment: There's nothing that can simplify Core Data ;)